# getting ArrayList from HashSet

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I have a `HashSet< ArrayList < String >>` and I would like to get the `ArrayList<String>` out of the HashSet. How do I do this?

Comment: Any attempts so far from your side?

Comment: I tried using this. Lets name the HashSet< ArrayList< String >> as a. 

ArrayList< String > = HashSet.get(0); 

I don't know how HashSet works actually...

Comment: Remove your java syntax errors and provide a source code snipped that can be used.

Comment: First thing to do when you don't know how something in the Java API works: Check the API page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: Do you think if I understand anything from that Java API, I will be asking here?

Comment: @user3045664 In that case you should really learn how to read them; the API pages contain a lot of very important information and every developer should be able to use them.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to learn how to read them. Or not I won't be asking here trying to figure out what the API pages is talking about. In a sense, I'm trying to understand what the API says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most common way to do it:

```
HashSet<ArrayList<String>> set = assingYourSet();
for (Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) iterator.next();
// Do Stuff...
}
```

Comment: The most common way to do it ... 10 years ago before for-each loops came along.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `iterator()` function [described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#iterator%28%29) to get hold of an iterator on the HashSet and then get the elements from that.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` implements the `Iterable` interface so you can loop over it with a foreach loop:

```
HashSet<ArrayList<String>> arrayListSet = ...;
for (ArrayList<String> arrayList : arrayListSet) {
  // Use arrayList here
}
```